# VS Code não reconhece métodos do objeto event

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-eventos

O meu VS Code não reconhece os métodos e parâmetros do objeto event quando este é enviado por uma função anônima como parâmetro de outra função.

Neste caso você vê funcionar.
[image]

Neste não funciona.

[image]

eu já instalei quase todas as extensões do VS e não sei pq isso não funciona. Se alguém puder ajudar.

Informações extras: o código em sí não importa, apenas o problema com o "e".
O `console.log(e)` retorna o event, não há problema de undefined.

Comment: O TypeScript iria te ajudar tanto nessas horas.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nem o TypeScript ajudaria nesse tipo de situação. Há uma falta de informações necessária para a “inferência” de tipos.

O problema é que o compilador (utilizado internamente pelo VSCode) não possui informações o suficiente para saber qual é o tipo do parâmetro `e`.

Portanto, até que você adicione a informação necessária para determinar o tipo daquele parâmetro, não haverá nada para se "inferir", já que o chamador pode, em tese, passar qualquer coisa como argumento ali.

No TypeScript, essa informação poderia ser adicionada com uma anotação de tipos explícita. Por exemplo:

```
function handleEvent(e: Event) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIZgCYBsCmBRANxzCgAocAuRQ4qASkQG8AoRNxCBAZzlwDoscAObk%20UVACchOegG5mAX2bMMcCCAC2tPgCM4GAJ59UGDDRIAZGFyjEcE0gHIIWGBADWjgDQp02fEQkdLJAA).

Se você não estiver utilizando TypeScript, é possível adicionar esse tipo de informação utilizando comentários JSDoc. O VSCode utiliza a infraestrutura do TypeScript para fazer a tratativa dos tipos informados via JSDoc, de modo que o efeito será praticamente o mesmo em editores que o suportam.

Assim:

```
/**
 * @param {Event} e
 */
function handleEvent(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhCgAIUgBAHAhgJ0QW0gbwKIDcCmAdgC4C%20k%20UIw4AZgK6EDGxAlgPaGQAWihAJgBt8eIsQAU%20AJRYokeU04BndsIB0g9gHNJa4ii35iUgNzhS4cP3ZN6aMWoBG7fgE81ifv1EkAMqyViInxkcQByJkFWJgBrMIAaHj4hEQISUyA).

Saiba mais sobre o JSDoc na [referência](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html).

Note que, nos dois casos (embora de maneiras sintaticamente diferentes), adicionei o tipo `Event` ao parâmetro `e` da função `handleEvent`.

O tipo `Event` é o mais genérico para *handlers* de evento. Existem outros, tal como `MouseEvent`, `KeyboardEvent`, `SubmitEvent` etc, que podem ser utilizados para adicionar mais informações sobre um tipo específico de evento.

A lista completa encontra-se nas definições oficiais do TypeScript. [Aqui.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9c8a90d6853f1be97a78035d4909bccb6027c7e9/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado mesmo. Essa é a primeira vez que eu utilizo o Stackoverflow pra fazer uma pergunta e não sei exatamente como eu posso "fechar" ela ou algo assim. Com relação a resposta eu adicionei provisoriamente  o comentário JSDoc para este caso especifico e irei estudar o TypeScript quando encerrar meus estudos em JavaScript puro. Eu sei que o problema apenas afetava minha interação com o código e não o código em si, mas para quem está aprendendo ter estes auxílios é um divisor de águas. vlw mesmo.

Comment: @Coriast, de nada! E seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. :-) Sobre “fechar” a pergunta, você já fez o que era necessário: como encontrou uma resposta satisfatória, bastou a aceitar clicando no ícone de check.

Comment: _Nem o TypeScript ajudaria nesse tipo de situação_ - não entendi essa fala se logo em seguida você deu um exemplo com TypeScript  :/

Comment: @CmteCardeal, quis dizer que nem a linguagem TypeScript conseguiria ajudar só com o código postado na pergunta. No código original do AP, como disse, falta informação para que o “_intelli-sense_” seja feito. Claro que com o tipo do parâmetro informado, com ou sem TypeScript, o editor seria capaz de determinar os membros apropriados.